# Insertar datos de una fila de una tabla a otra tabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, pdo

Me gustaria pasar datos (fila) de una tabla a otra tabla.

Es decir:

```
**Tabla1:**

id-> 1,

Nombre-> "Jack",

Edad-> "122",

Sexo-> "Mujer"



**Tabla2:**

id

Nombre

Edad

Sexo
```

Coger los datos de una fila de la tabla1 e insertarlo como una nueva fila en la tabla2.

> Algoritmo pensado por mi, para que puedan entender mejor:

**INSERTAR `Tabla1` COLUMNAS `nombre`, `edad`, `sexo` VALORES (SELECCIONAR FROM `nombre`, `edad`, `sexo` WHERE `id` = 1)**

Comment: Saludos. Le sugiero poner el código que tienes actualmente para realizar el proceso,; así como el mensaje de error o en el resultado equivocado que te devuelve y como lo esperas.

Comment: Es correcto como lo tienes pensado. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: No me funciona.

Comment: El problema es de que como se podria insertar la fila esa de la tabla 1 a la tabla 2

Comment: Como te mencionó  A. Cedano, tu consulta debería funcionar. Si no está funcionando debe mostrarte algún error, podrías publicarlo?

Comment: La consulta quedaría así: `INSERT INTO Tabla1 (nombre, edad, sexo) SELECT  nombre, edad, sexo FROM Tabla2 WHERE id=1`, para más detalles, puedes ver [este enlace](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/).

Comment: Ahora ya me funciona, era un error de las comillas